# Maven snapshot jar and deployment of it

Tags: java, maven

Recently we converted our project to Maven.

I am new to maven and would like to know what is the best practice for jar getting deployed to the dev and prod environments.

Maven is creating the myproj-snapshot....jar in the target folder.

Is the snapshot jar is the one that need to deployed to environments or the myproj.jar always??

Please help me understand this.

Comment: is your application a Spring Boot application?

Comment: The `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` is defined as being on the road to the release `1.0.0`. Usually this means dev is related to SNAPSHOT whereas release `1.0.0` is related to the prod environment. But today usually you create a release which is deployed somewhere to exactly identify the state. That might mean `1.0.0`, `1.0.1` etc. will be created but in the end is not really a problem. Each release should be created by defined process (for example maven-release-plugin or similar) which defines the exact state via version control tag etc.

Comment: Thanks for you responses. no not using spring boot yet. It's a simple java batch job. we currently run our with a java command thru a cron job. Now using maven creating jar with dependencies. so, to run the batch job I need to provide the jar file name in the java command like java -cp myproj-snapshot...,jar ,,,/my path/myclassfile .  Do, I need to change the shell script for each release then? can I just use something like myproj.jar in java the command . How does it work???

Comment: Any suggestions on this please